# Using "the" before the name of a railway station

Tags: general-vs-specific

Should I use "the" before the name of station ?

"the Shanghai Station"
or
"Shanghai Station"?

Comment: Downvoting with no explanation: isn't that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the proper name of a specific railway station [like Euston Station or Grand Central Station] there should be no 'the' and you should capitalize each word: Shanghai Station.  On the other hand, if you're talking generally about a place where you don't know the actual name, you might say, e.g. "Get to the Canterbury station and take a train to London."